# StackOverFlowError when loading multiple advanceddatagrids

Tags: apache-flex

I have two custom advanced datagrids on a tabbed navigator(one per tab) to the right of the main datagrid that lists options for the user to select. When user clicks a line item on the main datagrid the advanced datagrids in the tabbed navigator will then load with appropriate information. The issue is that after I initially load the first selection the user makes, it will freeze when the user tries to make a second selection. HOWEVER, if the user decides to toggle the tabs(view both tabs 1 and 2) before making the second selection, all is well. If ONLY tab 1 is viewed before next selection is made... crash..

source for advanceddatagrid can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/advanceddatagrid/source/browse/trunk/mergeableDataGrid/src/AdvancedDataGrid/AdvancedDataGrid.mxml?r=3

I have modified how the grid loops through the xml though which can be seen in the below snippet

```
        public function createGrid(xml:XML):void
        {
            // create columns 
            var columns:ArrayList = new ArrayList();  

            var rows:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 

            for each (var column:XML in xml.Columns.Column)
            {
                var col:AdvancedDataGridColumn = new AdvancedDataGridColumn();

                col.dataField = column.DataField.valueOf().toString(); 
                col.headerText = column.Name.valueOf().toString();
                col.dataTipField = column.Tooltip.valueOf().toString();
                col.showDataTips = true;

                columns.addItem(col);
            }

            this.dataProvider = xml.Rows.Row;

            this.groupedColumns = columns.toArray();
        }
```

here is my tabbed navigator code

```
    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabNavigator"  width="100%" height="100%">         
        <s:VGroup width="100%"
                 label="Financial">
            <s:HGroup height="100%"
                      width="100%"
                      gap="0">
                <dataGrid:AdvancedDataGrid id="fundingGrid"
                                           itemEditBeginning="fundingGrid_itemEditBeginningHandler(event)"
                                           itemEditEnd="fundingGrid_itemEditEndHandler(event)"
                                           width="100%"
                                           height="100%"/>          

            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:VGroup width="100%"
                 label="Quarterly Breakdown">
            <s:HGroup height="100%"
                     width="100%">
                <dataGrid:AdvancedDataGrid id="quarterlyBreakdownGrid"
                                           width="85%"
                                           height="100%"
                                           itemEditBeginning="quarterlyBreakdownGrid_itemEditBeginningHandler(event)"
                                           itemEditEnd="quarterlyBreakdownGrid_itemEditEndHandler(event)"/>     
                <s:Button id="btnSaveQuarterlyBreakdown"
                          label="Submit"
                          toolTip="Click to save program's quarterly funding."
                          click="btnSaveQuarterlyBreakdown_clickHandler(event)"/>

            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
```

When the user selects a line item from grid the advanced datagrids are sent xml with the column names and rows.. this createGrid method is in the first code snippet.

```
this.fundingGrid.createGrid(fundingXML);
this.quarterlyBreakdownGrid.createGrid(bdXML);
```

Error Message

> Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
>       at mx.styles::StyleManager$/getStyleManager()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/getStyleManager()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/getTypeHierarchy()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/matchesCSSType()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/matchesCSSType()
>       at mx.styles::CSSSelector/matchesStyleClient()
>       at mx.styles::CSSStyleDeclaration/matchesStyleClient()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/matchStyleDeclarations()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/getClassStyleDeclarations()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/getClassStyleDeclarations()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/getMatchingStyleDeclarations()
>       at mx.styles::StyleProtoChain$/initProtoChain()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initProtoChain()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/regenerateStyleCache()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::addingChild()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/addChild()
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGrid/addRendererToContentArea()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGrid.as:2125]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGrid/createHeaderItems()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGrid.as:5968]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGrid/createHeaders()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGrid.as:2257]
>       at mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses::AdvancedDataGridBase/makeRowsAndColumns()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\advancedDataGridClasses\AdvancedDataGridBase.as:822]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGridBaseEx/makeRowsAndColumns()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.as:2213]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGrid/makeRowsAndColumns()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGrid.as:1999]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::AdvancedListBase/makeRowsAndColumnsWithExtraRows()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\listClasses\AdvancedListBase.as:4002]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::AdvancedListBase/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\listClasses\AdvancedListBase.as:3574]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGridBaseEx/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.as:2016]
>       at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGrid/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGrid.as:2899]
>       at mx.core::ScrollControlBase/setScrollBarProperties()

Any ideas? I know this may seem confusing.. willing to elaborate more if necessary.

Comment: After toying around looks like this did the trick.

    this.quarterlyBreakdownGrid.validateDisplayList();

After my create grid calls.